# Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition can not move to current record in the form

Tags: ms-access

i have a form with data sheet view i want to use this form as a list box (multi select extended), so when i click on each record/field in the form it uses (clear selection function) for unselected other records and just select record i have focused, now problem is when click on each field after running clear selection function it goes to the first record and did not moves cursor to current focused record.

it seems below code

```
 Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = Pos1
```

does not work and will not be moved to current focused record.

the complete code is like below:

```
  Private Sub P_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Dim ct As Control
Dim Cnt As Long, Rws As Long
Dim Pos1 As Long, Pos2 As Long

Pos1 = Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition

Set ct = ActiveControl


' Clear other selections if Ctrl or Shift key
' is not simultaneously pressed.
If CtrlPressed = 0 And ShiftPressed = 0 Then
   P_ClearSelections

   Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = Pos1



    Me.IsSelected = True

    ct.SetFocus
    GoTo ExitPoint
End If

If ShiftPressed > 0 Then
    Rws = Me.SelHeight
    If Rws > 1 Then
        Pos2 = Me.SelTop - 1
        For Cnt = Pos2 To Pos2 + Rws - 1
            Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = Cnt
            Me.IsSelected = True
        Next
    End If
    GoTo ExitPoint
End If

Me.IsSelected = True

 ExitPoint:
' Save the status
Me.Dirty = False
' Update display in SF_Selected
Me.Parent("SF_Selected").Requery

ActiveControl.SelLength = 0

Set ct = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
 End Sub
```

**function clear selection is like below;**

```
   Public Sub P_ClearSelections()
On Error Resume Next

DoCmd.Echo False
' Clear all check boxes
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblItems " & _
        "SET IsSelected = False;", dbFailOnError
Me.Requery


DoCmd.Echo True

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: According to your code, you are moving to the position that you just saved.  Which means that you attempted to move to the record that you are already displaying.

Comment: i want to move to the position i clicked,when i click (Pos1 = Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition) i save the position i clicked , so after clear function and (Me.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = Pos1) it seems should move to clicked item.but it does not move and keep first record.

Comment: I would first remove the `On Error Resume Next` statements - you need to see any error message(s). I suspect that Pos1, Pos2 should also be declared as Variants although I haven't looked at this is detail (because the error-handling is disabled ;)). I hope that you don't apply `On Error Resume Next` to every procedure?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requerying the underlying recordset in your `P_ClearSelections()` procedure. From the Microsoft documentation:

> There is also no assurance that a given record will have the same
>   AbsolutePosition if the Recordset object is requeried or reopened.
>   Bookmarks are still the recommended way of retaining and returning to
>   a given position and are the only way of positioning across all types
>   of Recordset objects.

[MSDN AbsolutePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I suggest that you investigate the use of `Bookmarks` instead (and remove the `On Error Resume Next` statements).